# Convert timezone name to city name (remove continent part)

Tags: java, string

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out to to remove part of a string. I am using the java.util.TimeZone to retrieve time zone "ids" but I want to delete the continent/ prefix, basically stripping out the city name. I also have to replace all underscores with spaces which I have done in code already. I just can not seem to find a way to get rid of the backslash and everything before it. Here is my code. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;

public class Maps {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  String[] Zone = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

  int i = 0;

   for (i =0 ; i< Zone.length; i++) {
    String zone1 = Zone[i].replaceAll("_"," "); 

    System.out.println(zone1);
   }   
 }        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So you want to remove everything before the first slash, and then replace any underscores in the remainder with spaces? That's fairly easy using `indexOf`, `substring` and `replace` (which you're already aware of).

You certainly *could* do this with regular expressions as suggested by Mr_Spock, but personally for just a couple of operations I'd stick with the normal string methods:

```
int slash = text.indexOf('/');
text = text.substring(slash + 1).replace("_", " ");
```

So for a complete example:

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

        for (String id : ids) {
            int slash = id.indexOf('/');
            String stripped = id.substring(slash + 1).replace("_", " ");
            System.out.println(stripped);
        }
    }   
}
```

Note that this still leaves you with some interesting names such as "North Dakota/Beulah" as the original ID had two slashes in.

Just for completeness, another way of handling the slash is to split the string on slash and then take the second part - but as the above example shows, you then probably want to make sure that it splits into *at most* two parts, keeping "North Dakota/Beulah" as a single token. You'd also need to be careful in case there were any IDs without *any* slashes (the above code works fine as `indexOf` will return -1, so the substring will become a no-op).

Comment: Thanks for verifying the validity of my approach.  Great answer.  +1

Answer (score 2):

I would try to approach this in an unorthodox fashion for the average Java coder (I assume).  I'd try to utilize the power of regular expressions.

Try exploring the world of [**java.util.regex**](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/)

It doesn't hurt to learn about RegEx, as it's used in string manipulation solutions across the board.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
              public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] Zone = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

         int i = 0;

       for (i =0 ; i< Zone.length; i++) {
        String zone1 = Zone[i].replaceAll("_"," ");

        if(zone1.indexOf('/') != -1)
          zone1 = zone1.substring(zone1.indexOf('/')+1);

        System.out.println(zone1);
       }   
}
```

Comment: `zone1.substring(zone1.indexOf('/') + 1);` is enough, no need for the second argument

Comment: This works!! Thanks so much, I am pretty new to programming so sorry if it was a very simple question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use just split the zone :-

```
String zone1 = Zone[i];
zone1 = (zone1.split("/").length > 1) ? zone1.split("/")[1] : zone1.split("/")[0];
zone1 = zone1.replaceAll("_"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(zone1.indexOf("/")!=-1) {
        zone1=zone1.substring(zone1.indexOf("/")+1,zone1.length());
        System.out.println(zone1);
    }
```